# C++ Lightweight Web Framework

Tags: c++, user-interface, nancy

I have been using Nancy Framework for my C# Applications to create Web-Based GUI's. Unfortunately I have not found anything for C++ that is of similar style or ease of use. Are there any all around good solutions for this type of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [cpp-netlib](http://mikhailberis.github.com/cpp-netlib/)? See for example their [hello world server](http://mikhailberis.github.com/cpp-netlib/hello_world_server.html).

Comment: The main thing (which I should have mentioned originally) is Nancy Framework allows me to basically call C# functions from my web pages, get results, even work C# style code in them. This is what I am looking for, but not sure if it exists for C++.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least two, in fact:

- Wt, C++ Web Toolkit:
  http://www.webtoolkit.eu/‎
- CppCMS — High Performance C++ Web Framework: http://cppcms.com/‎